# Check disk space against a threshold

Tags: file-system, linux, shell, sh, posix

The below script is one I made to check the disk space on mounted partitions under Debian Wheezy. I tried adding a `-d` switch to force printing out the used data, but its main purpose is to run as a cron job, and email the administrator if any disks are below a certain threshold.

What I'm looking for is to make sure it's POSIX compliant (in case it needs to be called by another script/application), and that it's rock solid. It works on my servers as is, with and without the `-d`. It requires that if an argument is given, it's a mount point. I am trying to get the proper coding practices done properly, as well.

```
#!/bin/sh

MOUNTPOINTS="/ /var /home" #The mount points to always check; the user can
                           #specify more via the command line, or changing this.
THRESHOLD=85    #The amount of disk space used before printing the warning.
DEBUG=false     #If TRUE when running (-d switch) lists all mount points, even if
                #the threshold has not been met.

while getopts ":dh" opt; do
        case $opt in
                d)
                        DEBUG=true
                        ;;
                h)
                        echo USAGE: $0 \[-d\] \[\/mount\/point\/1 ...\]
                        exit 0
                        ;;
                \?)
                        echo Incorrect syntax
                        ;;
        esac
        shift $((OPTIND - 1))
done

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        for var in $@; do
                MOUNTPOINTS="${MOUNTPOINTS} ${var} "
        done
fi

for MOUNT in ${MOUNTPOINTS}; do
  CURRENT=$(df ${MOUNT} | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
  if ($DEBUG); then
    printf "%20s\t%s\n" ${MOUNT} ${CURRENT}%
  fi
  if [ "${CURRENT}" -gt "${THRESHOLD}" ] ; then
      echo "Your ${MOUNT} partition\'s remaining space is critically low. Used: ${CURRENT}%"
    fi

done
```

Comment: That shift is before the `done` of the `while` loop. And yes, spaces and other shell glob characters `*`, `[]` and `?`.

Comment: What I meant was that in my script, I moved it (I was told not to "edit" original scripts on Code Review, but create a new question after taking many helpful hints into account)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your comment then. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a string for `MOUNTPOINTS` means you can't have any mount points with spaces of glob characters in the names. I realize you likely can't use an array if you want real portability but that's a severe limitation that you might want to check for.

I don't know what you can do (without using an array) that will allow directories like that to work but you can check the input arguments for compatibility and disallow any that don't fit those limitations.

As I said on some other question (of yours I believe) that shift in the `while` loop is incorrect. You are shifting off (an increasing number of arguments) *during* the getopts processing. You want to do that shift **once** and **after** getopts is done.

Try this and see what I mean:

```
$ cat test-getopts.sh
#!/bin/sh

while getopts ":dh" opt; do
    case $opt in
        d) echo DEBUG=true;;
        h) echo HELP;;
        \?) echo error;;
    esac
    printf 'Shifting %d\n' $((OPTIND - 1))
    shift $((OPTIND - 1))
done
$ /bin/sh go.sh -d -h -d -h -d -h -d -h -d -h -d -h
DEBUG=true
Shifting 1
DEBUG=true
Shifting 2
HELP
Shifting 3
HELP
Shifting 4
```

There is almost never a reason to pipe grep to awk or sed to awk or awk to sed. awk can  almost certainly do everything you need.

So the `grep | awk | sed` part of `$(df ${MOUNT} | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')` can be replaced by a single awk call:

```
`$(df "${MOUNT}" | awk '/\/{gsub(/%/, ""); print}')`
```

You'll also notice I quoted `"${MOUNT}"` there. In general you always want to quote shell variable expansions. In this case it can't actually matter since anything these quotes would protect will already have been expanded/word-split by the `for MOUNT in ${MOUNTPOINTS}` loop but it is the right thing to do anyway.

Also related to `df` if you are going to try to field-parse the output you want to use the `-P`/`--portability` option. It keeps `df` (at least from coreutils) from wrapping long lines to get columns to line up (and breaking field counts).

The syntax of `if` tests in the shell does not require wrapping parentheses. In fact, adding them spawns a sub-shell. So `if ($DEBUG); then` is running the value of `$DEBUG` as a command in a sub-shell. If you were to have set `DEBUG=debug` instead of `DEBUG=true` you'd have gotten an error from that because `debug` isn't a valid command. Drop them and use a non-empty or value checking test instead. Either `if [ -n "$DEBUG" ];` or `if [ "$DEBUG" = DEBUG ];`.

You don't need to quote single quotes in a double quoted string so:

```
echo "Your ${MOUNT} partition\'s remaining space is critically low. Used: ${CURRENT}%"
```

should be echoing `partition\'s` out which probably isn't what you want.

`for var in $@; do` can be simplified to `for var; do` if you wanted and if you don't then you should use `for var in "$@"; do` though again given that spaces/glob characters are going to be a problem later this isn't as useful as it might be (though it does let you test for them correctly and avoid them as discussed above).

Also, if you haven't already, you should run your code through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: That shellcheck thing is pretty cool, book marked! I'll admit, I know very little about `awk` or `sed` yet, and I'm trying to incorporate small bits at a time. I appreciate your help, here and on SO

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of concerns I have here, some of them style related, but mostly about the actual functionality....

### mounts

`/var` and `/home` may not necessarily be actual mount points. You should first check to see whether it is a mount point before testing it. This is because it may inaccurately reflect the `/` space if it is not actually a mount.

Additionally, it is (remotely) possible that, even if it is normally a mount point, that the partition may be unmounted too, but that's a remote problem.

The program `/bin/mountpoint` is a useful one for identifying whether a folder is in fact a mountpoint. It returns a useful exit code (0 if it is).

```
/bin/mountpoint -q / && echo YES
```

I would also possibly recommend that you just check all mounted filesystems. Something like this will do you well:

```
# Get mounts that come from non-kernel "magic" places.
grep -e '^/' /proc/mounts | cut -d' ' -f2
```

### `/boot`

Additionally, I highly recommend that you test the `/boot` folder. More than any other folder, this one has been a problem for me personally.

`/boot` is used for your kernel images, and it is relatively common to apply system updates, and then forget to remove old images. The `/boot` folder is quite small, and often can have less than 10 kernel images.... This has resulted in a few problems for me. Add `/boot` to your 'default' list of partitions to check. It will remind you to remove old and unused kernel versions, and prevent failed updates.

### Why shell? Got Perl?

```
df -h | perl -ne 'chomp; $line = $_; $_ =~ s/.*?\s+(\S+)\%.*/$1/; next unless $_ eq "Use" or $_ > 80; print "$line\n";'
```

For me that outputs:

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/mediavg-medialv    1.8T  1.7T   17G 100% /multimedia
/dev/mapper/snapvg-snaplv      2.7T  2.4T  349G  88% /snapshotng
```

(Filesystems with > 80% usage).

Youa re aware that the df command will go a long way to solving the whole thing for your, right?

### grep/awk/sed

> ```
> df ${MOUNT} | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'
> ```

This is a complicated line. I'm pretty sure you can get awk to do the whole thing for you...

Comment: Good point about checking for a real mountpoint and the `mountpoint` command. Also about just munging the `df` output directly for this instead of faffing about with finding mountpoints.

Comment: Currently, it works even without the mount points being actual mount points - As in, if I have one large `/` partition only, it still works with any other folder. You're right, I should do error checking as well. As for Perl, I want to learn only a few languages at a time, then try other languages. Eventually, I'd like to have a `.conf` file to read from, and probably store the variables there, but that's for a later date

Comment: The perl section is only an indication that parsing the output from df as a group is probably better than building your own df-with-a-threshold system. `df` can do all the heavy lifting for you.... use it.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers made very good points,
in the following I will mention only what was missed.

---

First of all, don't be afraid to use Bash instead of `/bin/sh`. Bash must exist in any decent system today, and it will enable you to use arrays, which would simplify the handling of mount points with spaces.

That said, for the record, there is a way to make the script work with spaces in mount point names without arrays, like this:

```
for path; do
    MOUNTPOINTS="$MOUNTPOINTS \"$path\""
done

eval "set -- $args"
```

A few things to note here:

- Don't do `for arg in $@`. If you have arguments "a" and "b c", then this will iterate over "a", "b", "c". You almost always want to do `for arg in "$@"` instead, which will correctly iterate over "a" and "b c".
- `for arg; do` is the same as `for arg in "$@"; do`, so you can use the shorter form
- The trick to make spaces in arguments work is to append to `MOUNTPOINTS` the arguments double-quoted, and then use an `eval`.
- `set -- a "b c"` command sets the positional arguments (the value of `$@`) to "a", "b c". We need to wrap this in an `eval` so the shell interprets the double-quotes that we added inside `MOUNTPOINTS`, otherwise they would be taken literally.
  However, as [@etan-reisner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/28012/etan-reisner) pointed out in a comment, although this is safe for spaces, it isn't safe for double quotes. It also allows for arbitrary command execution if the input does contain them.

I used this technique for many years to work around crappy old systems that didn't have Bash. 
Today, it's an unnecessary awkwardness. I recommend to use proper arrays instead. 
Also keep in mind that `eval` is generally considered *evil* and a last resort in all languages that have it.

If in some of the systems Bash is not at `/bin/bash`,
then you can use this shebang instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

---

The indentation is inconsistent. 
In the beginning you used a tab width of 8 spaces,
while at the end you used a tab width of 2 spaces.
It's better to be consistent throughout. (I use a width of 4.)
If you use `vim`, an easy way to reindent the entire file is with the `gg=G` command.

---

In some languages it is preferred to not use inline comments,
but put them on the line before the statement they refer to.
I like that idea because it often reduces the length of the line.
Keep in mind that long lines can be hard to read,
so it's good to keep line length short.

In some languages, when you use inline comments,
it's preferred to put at least two spaces in front of the comment marker,
and one space after the comment marker. So instead of this:

> ```
> MOUNTPOINTS="/ /var /home" #The mount points to always check; ...
> ```

This is preferred:

```
MOUNTPOINTS="/ /var /home"  # The mount points to always check; ...
```

---

Too many escape symbols hurt readability here:

> ```
> echo USAGE: $0 \[-d\] \[\/mount\/point\/1 ...\]
> ```

Better to use quotes so you don't need to escape:

```
echo "USAGE: $0 [-d] [/mount/point/1 ...]"
```

Btw, even in the first version, you didn't need to escape `/`.

---

In this part:

> ```
>     \?)
>         echo Incorrect syntax
>         ;;
> ```

Maybe it would be better to exit with an error, 
or to make the message more descriptive:

```
    \?)
        echo Incorrect option: $OPTARG
        ;;
```

---

> ```
> if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
> ```

You don't need to quote `$#`, as it's never empty.

---

> ```
>     MOUNTPOINTS="${MOUNTPOINTS} ${var} "
> ```

This could be simplified:

```
    MOUNTPOINTS="$MOUNTPOINTS $var"
```

That is, the `{}` and the trailing space were unnecessary.
If the `{}` make you feel more comfortable, and perhaps more readable,
then it's fine, there's nothing wrong with them,
I'm just lazy to type unnecessary things.

#### Putting it together

Using some of the suggestions from this and other answers,
I recommend this implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The mount points to always check; the user can
# specify more via the command line, or changing this.
MOUNTPOINTS=(/ /var /home)

# The amount of disk space used before printing the warning.
THRESHOLD=65

# If TRUE when running (-d switch) lists all mount points, even if
# the threshold has not been met.
DEBUG=false

while getopts ":dh" opt; do
    case $opt in
        d)
            DEBUG=true
            ;;
        h)
            echo "USAGE: $0 [-d] [/mount/point/1 ...]"
            exit 0
            ;;
        \?)
            echo Incorrect option: "$OPTARG"
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

for path; do
    MOUNTPOINTS+=("$path")
done

set -- "${MOUNTPOINTS[@]}"

for MOUNT; do
    test -d "$MOUNT" || continue
    CURRENT=$(df "$MOUNT" | awk '/\// {gsub(/%/, ""); print $5}')
    if [ $DEBUG = true ]; then
        printf "%20s\t%d%%\n" $MOUNT "$CURRENT"
    fi
    if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then
        echo "Your $MOUNT partition's remaining space is critically low. Used: $CURRENT%"
    fi
done
```

Comment: The `eval "set -- $args"` trick may be safe for spaces but isn't safe for double quotes (and as such allows for arbitrary command execution if the input does contain them).

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner, I amended my answer, paraphrasing your comment.